# Pass additional information to ActionMailer Observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, observer-pattern

I need to save information about sending every e-mail to my client in database for further analysis. So I'm trying to do it in Observer but there I need info about invoices.
So I've got Mailer:

```
class ClientMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "no-reply@tori-app.herokuapp.com"

  def remind(client, invoices)
    @client = client
    @company = @client.company
    @invoices  = invoices.to_a

    @template = t('message.template')

    @text = liquid_parse @template
    @html = markdown_parse @text

    mail(:to => @client.email, :subject => t('message.title')) do |format|
      format.html
      format.text
    end
  end

  private
    def markdown_parse(text)
      markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new Redcarpet::Render::HTML,
        :autolink => true, :space_after_headers => true
      markdown.render text
    end

    def liquid_parse(text)
      renderer = Liquid::Template.parse text
      renderer.render 'company' => @company, 'invoice' => @invoice, 'client' => @client
    end
end
```

And question is: how to pass `@invoices` to ActionMailer observer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've done it by myself by adding in mailer:

```
headers 'X-Invoice-IDs' => @invoices.map(&:id).join(';')
```

And then in observer

```
ids = message.header['X-Invoice-IDs'].to_s.split ';'
```

And there I've got all Invoice IDs in my observer.

**EDIT**

After thursday meeting of [PRUG](http://prug.pl/) I came with idea of overloading `delivery` method instead of using observer. It will be compatible with Rails 4 and easier to use (as I won't need passing additional header, I will use just instance variable).